# Meanings of parentheses in C++ and C

Tags: c++, c

I just had a nasty bug in C++. So I had list of registers and values, that are wrapped in a struct and then those structs are initialized in an array. But then I accidentally typed `()` instead of `{}`. Here is some test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct reg_val {
        unsigned reg;
        unsigned val;
};

struct reg_val faulty_array[] = { 
        {0x5001, 0xff},
        {0x5580, 0x01},
        (0x5580, 0x02), //<- THIS LINE IS THE PROBLEM
        (0x5589, 0x00), //<- AND THIS LINE
};

struct reg_val good_array[] = { 
        {0x5001, 0xff}, 
        {0x5580, 0x01}, 
        {0x5580, 0x02},
        {0x5589, 0x00},
};

int main()
{
        unsigned i;
        unsigned faulty_size = sizeof(faulty_array) / sizeof(struct reg_val);
        printf("Size of faulty array: %d\n", faulty_size);

        for (i = 0; i < faulty_size; ++i) {
                printf("faulty reg: %x  val: %x\n", faulty_array[i].reg,
                       faulty_array[i].val);
        }   

        unsigned good_size = sizeof(good_array) / sizeof(struct reg_val);
        printf("\nSize of good array: %d\n", good_size);
        for (i = 0; i < good_size; ++i) {
                printf("good reg: %x  val: %x\n", good_array[i].reg,
                       good_array[i].val);
        }   
        return 0;
}
```

I am more familiar with C and to my surprise this still compiled with g++:

```
$ g++ -Wall array.cc
array.cc:11: warning: left-hand operand of comma has no effect
array.cc:12: warning: left-hand operand of comma has no effect
array.cc:13: warning: missing braces around initializer for ‘reg_val’
$ ./a.out 
Size of faulty array: 3
faulty reg: 5001  val: ff
faulty reg: 5580  val: 1
faulty reg: 2  val: 0       <-- the first value gets discarded as mentioned in the compiler warning

Size of good array: 4
good reg: 5001  val: ff
good reg: 5580  val: 1
good reg: 5580  val: 2
good reg: 5589  val: 0
```

This code would obviously fail to compile with a C compiler, what's the difference in C++ that makes a C++ compiler (although grudgingly) accept this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question, I will first answer: Why does this fail to compile in C? Well, it fails to compile due to:

```
initializer element is not constant
```

For good measure, let's drop the `{}`s from C:

```
struct reg_val faulty_array[] = { 
        {0x5001, 0xff},
        {0x5580, 0x01},
        0x5580, 0x02, //<- THIS LINE IS THE PROBLEM
        0x5589, 0x00, //<- AND THIS LINE
};
```

Now the program outputs:

```
Size of faulty array: 4
faulty reg: 5001  val: ff
faulty reg: 5580  val: 1
faulty reg: 5580  val: 2
faulty reg: 5589  val: 0
```

This is perfectly allowed by the C standard (and C++). C (and C++) flatten braces to initialize elements of structures (this will come back). Your code fails in C because objects with static storage duration must initialized with constant expressions or with aggregate initializers containing constant expressions. C does not treat `(0x5580, 0x02)` as a constant expression.

This (unhappily) compiles in C++ because C++ treats the comma operator between two constant expressions as a constant expression, so your code is more like:

```
struct reg_val faulty_array[] = { 
        {0x5001, 0xff},
        {0x5580, 0x01},
        0x02,
        0x00,
};
```

...which is, of course, allowed.

```
struct reg_val faulty_array[] = { 
        {0x5001, 0xff},
        {0x5580, 0x01},
        {0x02, 0x00},
};
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. I see. That makes sense. But gcc seems to be not very happy about me "flattening braces". `$ gcc -Wall array.c
array.c:13: warning: missing braces around initializer`

Comment: `gcc` with `-Wall` will also warn you about `if (c = something())` because `suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value`. Just because something is allowed by ANSI C doesn't mean it won't generate a warning.

Comment: you are right, `gcc -std=c89 -pedantic array.c` compiles without warnings.

Answer (score 4):

What makes you think it would fail to compile in C?

C++: http://ideone.com/KLPh4
C: http://ideone.com/VYUbL

**Pay attention to your warnings.**  I can't stress this enough.  Warnings are there to help you catch mistakes like this.

Well, the error message in C makes the difference perfectly clear: C requires the initializers to be constants, not arbitrary expressions.  It makes no sense to me why those aren't considered constants, since this compiles fine in C:

- http://ideone.com/p5I1d

Comment: It does fail to compile in C-land because "initializer element is not constant." In other words: `(expr, expr)` is not a constant expression or an aggregate initialization.

Comment: The C standard refers to a *constant* as what we in C++ would call a *literal*. If you have `const int C = 5`, then `C` is not a constant.

Comment: @Travis: See the final example, which uses an expression, not a literal, but IS a valid initializer.

Comment: But it is an expression made of only literals :-) . I'm definitely way more fuzzy on the C spec than the C++ one.

Comment: @BenVoigt It requires a "constant expression", simple arithmetic expressions with integer constants are still constant expressions. Comma operator applications aren't. Now, why `(constant_expression, constant_expression)` is not a constant expression, you'd have to ask the committee.

Comment: Perhaps it's a bug but clang seems to think the comma expressions are valid initializers in C.

Comment: @bames53 Yes, it's a bug, 6.6.(3) says "Constant expressions shall not contain assignment, increment, decrement, function-call, or comma operators, except when they are contained within a subexpression that is not evaluated" (n1570 and C99).

Comment: @bames53 Oh, perhaps not a bug, paragraph 10 says "An implementation may accept other forms of constant expressions."

Comment: @DanielFischer yep, found a bug report here to add pedantic checking: http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=4402

Comment: I changed my mind, reading through these answers, I am now more surprised that this doesn't compile in C ...

Answer (score 3):

C++ has a comma operator that evaluates both of its operands and returns the value of its right operand, ignoring its left. [You can see it more clearly here.](http://codepad.org/POEMaIlt)

And C too, apparently =) (Thanks, @BenVoigt)

Comment: The question is "What's the difference in C++ (compared to C)?"  The answer is not "the comma operator".

Comment: @BenVoigt: I don't know C, I'm just explaining the reason it does compile in C++ and I assumed he tried compiling it in C and that particular part failed. Sorry.

Comment: And I would assume that C++ tries to evaluate these expressions at compile time when they have constant operands, and C does not, which explains the error vs. warning between C and C++